# How to check a string includes or doesnot include certain words from array?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, string

Suppose I have two array:

```
const rejectBill = ['cancel', 'delete', 'discard', 'erroneously']

const readBill = ['bill','account','amount']
```

And I have an string ,

```
const stringBill = 'Read bill from text to be cancelled'
```

I want to check if bill contains words from readBill then return true but if it also contains word from rejectBill then return false.

For this I tried:

```
let stringSatus = readBill.some(keyword => stringBill.toLowerCase().includes(keyword.toLowerCase())) && 
                   !rejectBill.some(keyword => stringBill.toLowerCase().includes(keyword.toLowerCase()))
```

But on console of stringSatus, it gives false.

I want stringStatus to be true when string contains words from readBill array doesnot contain word from rejectBill array and false when string contains word from rejectBill.

If any one needs any more information please let me know.

Comment: `stringBill` has `'bill'` from `readBill` and `'cancel'` from `rejectBill` so the condition returns `false`.

Comment: Do you want to check for full word match or did you not notice `cancelled` in your string? You'd have to use [word boundaries](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) and regex if you want to treat `cancel` and `cancelled` as different words

Comment: If you want to check for exact word matches, you could do `const words = new Set(stringBill.toLowerCase().split(' ')); readBill.some(word => words.has(word.toLowerCase())) && !rejectBill.some(word => words.has(word.toLowerCase()))`.

Answer (score 0):

### Using Regex

I have created a `regex` on the fly based on the `string[]` and test if the `string` passes the `regex`.

```js
const rejectBill = ['cancel', 'delete', 'discard', 'erroneously'];

const readBill = ['bill', 'account', 'amount'];

const stringBill = 'Read bill from text to be cancelled';

var rejectBillRegex = new RegExp(rejectBill.map(t => `\\b${t}\\b`).join('|'), 'i'),
  readBillRegex = new RegExp(readBill.map(t => `\\b${t}\\b`).join('|'), 'i');

var stringSatus = readBillRegex.test(stringBill) && !rejectBillRegex.test(stringBill);
console.log(stringSatus)
```

Comment: Try with `'Pay the bill or cancel'`

Answer (score 0):

#### Using `String#split` and `Set`.

---

You can split the string by spaces using `String#split` and then using a `Set` constructed out of the list check if splited array contains any (using `Array#some`) string that is present in the `Set`.

**NOTE:** It is currently case sensitive, you can use `toLowerCase()` or `toUpperCase()` to make it case insensitive.

```js
const 
  rejectBill = ["cancel", "delete", "discard", "erroneously"],
  readBill = ["bill", "account", "amount"],
  stringBill = "Read bill from text to be cancelled",
      
  strInList = (str, lst, set = new Set(lst)) => str.split(" ").some((s) => set.has(s)),

  isRead = strInList(stringBill, readBill) && !strInList(stringBill, rejectBill);

console.log(isRead);
```

Answer (score -2):

From taking a quick look at your code, it seems like it does work as attended. Your example, "Read bill from text to be cancelled," is returning false because it detects the word "'cancel'led." If you were to remove 'cancel' from 'cancelled,' it would return true. If you are looking to check for spaces, I would add a space after each value in readBill and rejectBill, as so:

```
const rejectBill = ['cancel ', 'delete ', 'discard ', 'erroneously '];
const readBill = ['bill ', 'account ', 'amount '];
```

You would also need to add a fail-safe though for when stringBill ends in one of those words. That could easily be implemented by checking the last word of the string, stringBill. If you have any questions, feel free to leave a comment and I will help you out to the best of my ability!

Comment: Adding space to the keywords is a terrible idea.

Comment: I'd have to agree with you, I should've put a much better implementation. I think OP just initially made the mistake of not seeing cancel inside of 'canceled.'